# Grand Theft Auto 5 autosave

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, ps4

My sister turned off my PS4 in the middle of my triathlon on Grand Theft Auto 5. With autosave will I be able to resume where I was in the triathlon?

Comment: Nope. The game did a checkpoint before the triathlon, so you would start from the start of the triathlon I think.

Comment: no. the game doesn't save at any point during a triathlon. nor does the game start up at the beginning of it either. i've had this happen to me before, and was extremely pissed, as it was the last one, which takes a good 30 mins+ to do. the game will just start up at the beach

Answer (score 1):

To piggy back and credit to the comment section above @ヴァイシャリ and @Nicholas Aysen - Unfortunately you will not spawn where you left off in the Triathlon.  This is because there is no save point / Auto-save anywhere during these events.

When your PS4 comes back on you will most likely spawn back on the beach near the starting line and will have to retry the triathlon.

I hope this helps!